# Populating HTML table based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple checkboxes on a HTML page, and I would like to be able to populate a table on a second HTML page based on what checkboxes have been clicked.

As a basic example, here is a div containing 2 of the checkboxes. I would like it so that if, say, `awareness_checkbox` was checked, the word Awareness and it's value (0.01 CPC) would be added to a table on my second HTML page.

How would be the best way to go about doing this? My intention is to have a HTML button that links to the second page (let's call it 'page2.html') so that when it is clicked, every checkbox that has been checked on the page has it's label and associated value added to a table that will appear on the second page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="campaignstrategy">
    <h1>1. Campaign Strategy</h1>
        <input type="checkbox" name="awareness" id="awareness_checkbox" value="0.01">Awareness<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="directresponse" id="directresponse_checkbox" value="0.01">Direct Response<br>
</div>
```

Comment: There are two separate questions in the post. You should ask a single question only. Also, it would be fair to share what you already have, and not just exploit the volunteers at SO to get your job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note

okay, so I re-did all the code and tested locally on chrome, just save both files in the same directory and then open page1.html in chrome.

## Code Extracts - Page 1

> Assign a custom action to the input button, this will check all checkbox input type inputs,
>
> it will then see whether or not it is checked, if it is checked then it will add an entry into `table_info` variable, after checking all inputs
>
> it will then convert the javascript object into a json string, then we convert that json into base64 encoded string.
>
> then we browse to the page2.html file and in the url we pass a key called "table_data" and its value is the base64 encoded string.

```
$('#next_page_button').click(function(){
    let table_info = [];
    $('.campaignstrategy input[type=checkbox]').each(
        function(index, value){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            table_info.push(
                {
                    name: $(this).attr('name'),
                    value: $(this).attr('value'),
                }
            );
        }
    });
    let base64str=btoa(JSON.stringify(table_info));

    window.location = "page2.html?table_data=" + base64str;
});
```

## Code Extracts - Page 2

> when this page is loaded into the browser, the following script will check the query keys, in this case we are looking for 'table_data' key.
>
> this will be accomplished by a helper function (see pastbin for details, left out to keep the answer short)
>
> once we have the data, we will decode it from base64 to json, then using the json.parse function we will recreate the javascript object.
>
> after creating the object, we will loop through the array, remember the javascript object that we decode is an array of dictionaries,
>
> `[{'name':'awareness','value':'0.01'}]` as you see, it has the checkbox's name and its associcated value.
>
> then we create the table row, and append the name and value to the table row inside a table data element, one for each name and value.

```
// actual code
let table_data = getUrlParameter('table_data');
let data_from_page_1 = JSON.parse(atob(table_data));

for(let i=0;i<data_from_page_1.length;i++){
    let row = $("<tr></tr>");
    let recordName = $("<td></td>").text(data_from_page_1[i].name);
    let recordValue = $("<td></td>").text(data_from_page_1[i].value);
    row.append(recordName, recordValue);
    $('#output_table').append(row);
}
```

## Examples

### Page 1

[image: page1.html]

### Page 2

[image: pages.html]

## Instructions

save the contents of this to a file called **page1.html** [Code Link For Page 1](https://pastebin.com/qWazAHuw)

save the contents of this to a file called **page2.html** [Code Link For Page 2](https://pastebin.com/acK1McHx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dean, i'm not sure it quite works but that might just be me!

Comment: Do I need to add anything to page2.html? This is not working for me

Comment: the code under the "page2.html" title is supposed to be on page 2.html

Comment: @bboooooyintheuk okay, so I completed this code, it works and you can test it, just create 2 HTML files, page1.html and page2.html with the correct code, via the links... then ta-da and you can look through the code to see how well I did

Comment: Can I message you about a follow on from this question? I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: just did! :) :) :)